# How to set "classification" type for a random forest in R

Tags: r

I have some training (`train`) and testing (`test`) data. This is the way I'm building a forest:

```
forest <- randomForest(y ~ . - y, data=train, nodesize=25, ntree=200, type="classification")
```

I wish to emphasize that `train$y` and `test$y` may take only integer values like `1, 2, 3, 4`, etc. But when I build my prediction like

```
pred = predict(forest, newdata=test, type="class")
```

And check `pred` contents with:

```
pred[1:10]
```

I see such an output:

```
3        5       12       14       26       27       33       48       50 
2.863208 2.466447 2.476652 2.894254 4.726897 2.378187 2.034159 3.977969 2.264780
```

Whereas I expected to see something like:

```
3         5        12      14
1         3         1       7    # <- I wish to see integers here
```

So, what is wrong with that?

Comment: It would help if you would provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I'm guessing your `y` values are numeric rather than a factor? Do you want to treat them as categorical variables? Perhaps try `randomForest(factor(y) ~ . - y, ...)`? You need to fit the model correctly depending on how you are interpreting your variables.

Comment: I checked it. `y` is of `int` type

Comment: You also don't need `y ~ . - y`. `y ~ .` is enough. The left hand side part of a formula is not included in the right hand side by default (when using `.`).

Comment: Thank you, guys! I will check it all

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows:

```
forest <- randomForest(factor(y) ~., data=train, nodesize=25, ntree=200)
```

here using `-y` in the formula is redundant as has been already mentioned by 'LyzandeR'